# Warning: Rtools is required

Tags: r, rtools

Every time when I install package this warning occurs :***WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:***

I have been using R-Studio since 4 months and I did not come across this warning before. Despite getting this warning every time my installation succeeds.

Comment: I can confirm. I'm seeing the same on windows machines without Rtools. You should report it to the RStudio support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022977/rtools-is-required-to-build-r-packages-but-is-not-currently-installed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here: [missing Rtools, should I be worried?](https://community.rstudio.com/t/missing-rtools-should-i-be-worried/27817)

> This means that if you are going to install packages that need compilation, you also have to install Rtools in your system.
>
> https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to translate the revolution measure from https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_42098685/article/details/105864543.

First step:
Download and install the right Rtools for your R.
Second step:
Tell the Rstudio where the Rtools is installed.
Use this command (the sentence between the ##) :

```
 writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"',con="~/.Renviron")
```

And it should Run as administrator.

Finally:
Type the sentence between ## to examine whether we have succeed:

```
 Sys.which("make")
```

if you see a path rather than blank it means it had succeed.
Like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve it is to go to the following link:
[1]: https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/

Download the Rtools, restart your computer and it´s all solved !!