# Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed

Tags: r, rtools

I am relatively new to R/RStudio. I was successfully able to install packages until today. Each time I try to install a package, I receive the following error:

*WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/my. Name/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/openintro_1.7.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3136068 bytes (3.0 MB)
downloaded 3.0 MB*

Rtools is already installed on my machine, so I'm not sure why it's not being recognized.

I have tried un-installing and re-installing rtools but can't seem to resolve the issue. Any insight here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Top of my head :  bad version of rtools, bad path environment variable on windows, bad directory location for installation, not the correct rights to access the rtools directory, etc. Check all these

Comment: Thank you. How am I able to check these? If it's one of the issues you've described, how can I resolve?

RTools installed under the path: C:\Rtools

Comment: Read this thread for more information about R/Rtools inner workings. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3563 
Check your windows PATH variable (google it if you need) and add to it as described in R documentation. Rights in windows are often resolved by starting RStudio as Administrator. 
And download only the last versions of Rstudio and Rtools. Also, you should be able to find more logs somewhere, google to find how to start Rstudio in verbose mode or something similar. Good luck with your struggle.

Comment: To check versions if Rtools is in C:\Rtools then from within R `file.show("C:/Rtools/version.txt")` will show its version and typing `R.version.string` will show the R version. the table at the web site https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ will show what version of Rtools you need for a given R version.  Also again assuming Rtools is at C:\Rtools check if C:\Rtools\bin, C:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin and C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin are on your Windows PATH.

Comment: What do you get when you type `devtools::find_rtools()`? And do you get this warning when you try to install the package `abind` for example, which does not require Rtools ?

Comment: @slp did you manage to resolve your problem with Rtools ?

Comment: I solved this finally by re-installing R.

Comment: Add Rtools path to System Environment variable

Comment: 90% of the time this is a path issue. It's easy to not choose the "modify my path" option when installing rtools.

Answer (score 11):

The message indicates RTools isn't installed properly. Download and install it like so:

1. Go [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)
2. Download rtools
3. Find the file that just downloaded
4. Double click on it to start installation
5. Close and reopen RStudio
6. Everything should work now!

A nice 2-minute video explainer can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSJX367HHh0).

---

Why is RTools [necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022977/rtools-is-required-to-build-r-packages-but-is-not-currently-installed/69112473?noredirect=1#comment135969939_69112473) in the first place?

> Rtools adds are some tools to allow you to build packages. Not all packages need it; just the ones that use C, C++ or Fortran code.

---

#### If you have problems installing

- If the instructions above don't result in a successful installation of Rtools, the following may help.
- [Re-install R](https://www.google.com/search?q=download+r). Try to stick to the default installation settings if possible. Don't forget to close all current R sessions before reinstalling, then start a new R session and see if it works as expected. If not, try downloading and installing Rtools as outlined at the top of this answer; hopefully it installs as expected now.
- Make sure your anti-virus software isn't preventing it being installed. Anti virus software can sometimes mistake it for something harmful and quarantine it.
- When reinstalling R, or when installing Rtools manually, be careful to look for any indication that you do not have write permissions to the drive you're installing to. If you don't have permission to install certain things, that may be what's causing Rtools to not install correctly. This is more likely to happen if there are multiple users on your Windows computer, or if your organisation has strict policies about what can be installed. To look into this, figure out where Rtools is being installed to, and ensure you have the ability to write to that folder.

Comment: Rtools isn't needed to call R from the command line.  Any installation of R allows that.  What Rtools adds are some tools to allow you to build packages.  Not all packages need it; just the ones that use C, C++ or Fortran code.

Comment: @user2554330 good catch. It seems the source of that info has since been removed (404 not found). I updated the answer to give the reason you provide in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

if your os is windows, you should install rtool to create a building env for some R packages.

full stack for install R Rstudio Rtool .

you can get answer from this video https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1Mv411u7Cm?spm_id_from=333.999.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had done all of that but it didn't work so I deleted the entire "C:\Program Files\R" files and reinstalled R.
I actually had two previous versions of R and Rtools and packages were not installed in the same folders

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).