# RStudio does not recognize installed Rtools40

Tags: r, rstudio

I repeatedly get the following error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please 
download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/OWNER/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/), ran Rtools40 installer as admin which gave no error. I put RTools on PATH using .Renviron, and as a check, the instructions say test this:

```
> Sys.which("make")
                              make 
"C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"
```

Yet i still get the same error from RStudio.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022977/rtools-is-required-to-build-r-packages-but-is-not-currently-installed) suggested reinstalling RTools (no help) and running RStudio as admin (no help). Otherwise that thread directs to a [similar](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3563) RStudio issue, but that is for an earlier version for RTools and at the end of the thread it instructs to RTools40 which is what I have.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be solved after I uninstalled R, RStudio, and RTools, and reinstalled everything again. I put R directly at C:\ root, because I have had previous problems with libraries and not having windows rights to program files folder. This may have contributed.