# Rstudio - Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am experiencing a R package loading issue when using the following package.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Here is the Error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: pluck<-, accumulate, accumulate2, accumulate_right, array_branch, array_tree, as_mapper, as_vector, assign_in, at_depth, attr_getter, auto_browse, chuck, compact, compose, cross, cross2, cross3, cross_d, cross_df, cross_n, detect, detect_index, discard, every, flatten_df, flatten_dfc, flatten_dfr, has_element, head_while, imap, imap_chr, imap_dbl, imap_dfc, imap_dfr, imap_int, imap_lgl, imap_raw, imodify, insistently, invoke_map, invoke_map_chr, invoke_map_dbl, invoke_map_df, invoke_map_dfc, invoke_map_dfr, invoke_map_int, invoke_map_lgl, invoke_map_raw, is_numeric, is_rate, is_scalar_numeric, iwalk, keep, lift, lift_dl, lift_dv, lift_ld, lift_lv, lift_vd, lift_vl, list_along, list_merge, list_modify, lmap, lmap_at, lmap_if, map, map2, map2_chr, map2_dbl, map2_df, map2_dfc, map2_dfr, map2_int, map2_lgl, map2_raw, map_at, map_call, map_chr, map_dbl, map_depth, map_df, map_dfc, ma
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘as_mapper.character’, ‘as_mapper.default’, ‘as_mapper.list’, ‘as_mapper.numeric’, ‘modify.character’, ‘modify.default’, ‘modify.double’, ‘modify.integer’, ‘modify.logical’, ‘modify.pairlist’, ‘modify2.character’, ‘modify2.default’, ‘modify2.double’, ‘modify2.integer’, ‘modify2.logical’, ‘modify_at.character’, ‘modify_at.default’, ‘modify_at.double’, ‘modify_at.integer’, ‘modify_at.logical’, ‘modify_depth.default’, ‘modify_if.character’, ‘modify_if.default’, ‘modify_if.double’, ‘modify_if.integer’, ‘modify_if.logical’, ‘print.purrr_function_compose’, ‘print.purrr_function_partial’, ‘print.purrr_rate_backoff’, ‘print.purrr_rate_delay’, ‘rate_sleep.purrr_rate_backoff’, ‘rate_sleep.purrr_rate_delay’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
```

Anyone has solution for this? It seems that it is not possible to use 'install.packages("tidyverse")' can get us there.

I am guessing it is because of the Rtools that needed for tidyverse. See below.

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

> install.packages("Rtools")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
```

Comment: Close all instances of `R`. For example all Rstudio or now posit instancies. Also close actual opened cloud posit. Then start a fresh R session and install tidyverse!

Comment: Thanks, I have installed the pacakge purr but not working. Also I don't have any cloud posit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022977/rtools-is-required-to-build-r-packages-but-is-not-currently-installed) - note that R tools is not an R package - it's mostly a compiler required to build R packages that do not come compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the most recent version of R, 4.2.2? If not, the issue may be that tidyverse is not installing properly due to an older version of R.

Comment: My R version is 4.1.3, and Rstudio version is 2022.0204, please see the system message of Rstudio below in my local PC: 

> install.packages("tidyverse")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

Comment: Have you looked here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022977/rtools-is-required-to-build-r-packages-but-is-not-currently-installed