# How to deal with install.packages( ) warning "package ‘Rtools’ is not available for this version of R"?

Tags: install.packages, rtools

When trying to install  `Rtools` , I get the message below. My R version is 4.1.2.

`install.packages("Rtools")`
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘Rtools’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Any ideas how to install Rtools?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022977/rtools-is-required-to-build-r-packages-but-is-not-currently-installed)

Answer (score 7):

What you need to do is the following:

1. Go to: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

You will see something like this:
[image]

2. Select the version of `Rtools` you want to download.
3. Execute the downloaded .exe file and use the defaults, including the default installation location of `C:\rtools43`

That should resolve the problem!

Hope this helps!