Receiving message "WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed"
im trying to install R package as follow:
install.packages("remotes") 
remotes::install_version("RcppEigen", version = "0.3.3.9.3")
remotes::install_github("jrs95/hyprcoloc", build_vignettes = TRUE)

when i run install.packages("remotes")
i get this
> install.packages("remotes")
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/remotes_2.5.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 430772 bytes (420 KB)
downloaded 420 KB

package ‘remotes’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpCSKz4v\\downloaded_packages

even though i already installed rtools
somebody familiar with this prob?

Make sure you're using/reinstalling the right Rtools version, also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415325/how-to-deal-with-install-packages-warning-package-rtools-is-not-available and the linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022977/rtools-is-required-to-build-r-packages-but-is-not-currently-installed
