# Error Rtools is required despite having already installed

Tags: r, rtools

I'm trying to install the packages 'ggplot', 'psych' and 'moments', but the console keep saying that I need to install Rtools even though I have already installed in my Windows.

I tried the following:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("psych")
install.packages("moments")
```

But I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/soyso/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/moments_0.14.1.zip'
```

But I have already installed, deleted and re-installed RTools on my device.

Comment: Literally, a similar titled (earlier) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022977/rtools-is-required-to-build-r-packages-but-is-not-currently-installed?rq=2. Would be good, if you can explain/describe why this thread does not solve your problem? Thanks

Comment: That question has fairly bad answers.  I don't know if the high rated one works or not, but its explanation is certainly wrong when it says Rtools is needed to run R from the command line.

Comment: You have downloaded and installed RTools but is it in your OS PATH variable? When I install RTools I many times (but not always) have to manually edit the Windows path.