How to install some R packages like DMwR, Rtools
I am not able to install packages like DMwR in my RStudio. System: Windows 11. I am using version 4 which is the latest.
Here is the error I am getting:

> install.packages("DMwR") #i tried installing but got error then again tried installing Rtools
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/PUSHPIT/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘DMwR’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages


#error when tried installing Rtools
> install.packages("Rtools")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/PUSHPIT/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages


Does this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022977/rtools-is-required-to-build-r-packages-but-is-not-currently-installed

Rtools is not an R package; rather, it is a collection of development tools outside of R (compilers etc.) that you need to install in order to build R packages from source. Rtools usually refers to the tools for Windows, although similar tools need to be installed on other operating systems. Please go to the appropriate link below for your OS and R version and follow the instructions:

Rtools for Windows
Development tools for MacOS

